# Is BottomNavigationView supported in SDK 22?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

It is a simple question.

Can I use BottomNavigationView in sdk 22?

I tested with emulator with sdk 22, and it seems to work well.

But, BottomNavigatoinView is released in SDK 25.
Does the provide backward compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BottomNavigatoinView is released in SDK 25

I am uncertain where you determined this.

`BottomNavigationView` is part of [the Design Support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView), which is being migrated to [the Material Components for Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView) (for when you migrate to AndroidX).

Both implementations work back to API Level 14.